# Backtracking to find n-element vectors whose elements add up to less than K

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, backtracking

I'm interested in the following problem mainly as a way to gain intuition about the backtracking algorithm, so I am not looking for alternative solutions that don't use backtracking.

**Problem: find all n-element vectors such that the sum of their elements is less than or equal to some number K. Each element in the vector is an integer.**

Example: if n = 3, and K = 10, then [9, 0, 0] and [5, 0, 5] are solutions, while [3, 1, 8] is not.

From [this site](https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/backtracking/), I've adapted python code to try to implement a solution.

Here is the general "backtracking engine" function:

```
def solve(values, safe_up_to, size):

    solution = [None] * size

    def extend_solution(position):
        for value in values:
            solution[position] = value
            if safe_up_to(solution, position):
                if position >= size-1 or extend_solution(position+1):
                    return solution
        return None

    return extend_solution(0)
```

And here is the function to check if the solution is "safe so far":

```
def safe_up_to(partial_solution, target = 100): 
   partial_solution = np.array(partial_solution)  # convert to np array 

   # replace None with NaN
   partial_solution = np.where(partial_solution == None, np.nan, partial_solution)

   if np.nansum(partial_solution) <= target: 
       return True
   else: 
       return False
```

However, when I run these two functions together, I only get a single vector of all zeroes.

```
solve(values=range(10), safe_up_to=safe_up_to, size=5)
```

How should I modify this code to get all feasible solutions?

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this? I recommend reading this relevant article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: A single vector of all zeros _is_ a solution.

Comment: You're right, Paul. I'll edit to say that I want all solutions. Alexander, thank you, that is a helpful resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a gently modified version of your code. I tried to make it work changing as little as possible:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

def solve(values, safe_up_to, size):

    solution = [None] * size

    def extend_solution(position):
        for value in values:
            solution[position] = value
            if safe_up_to(solution):
                if position >= size-1:
                    yield np.array(solution)
                else:
                    yield from extend_solution(position+1)
        solution[position] = None

    return extend_solution(0)

def safe_up_to(target, partial_solution): 
   partial_solution = np.array(partial_solution)  # convert to np array 

   # replace None with NaN
   partial_solution = np.where(partial_solution == None, np.nan, partial_solution)

   if np.nansum(partial_solution) <= target: 
       return True
   else: 
       return False 

for sol in solve(values=range(10), safe_up_to=partial(safe_up_to,4), size=2):
    print(sol,sol.sum())
```

Prints:

```
[0 0] 0
[0 1] 1
[0 2] 2
[0 3] 3
[0 4] 4
[1 0] 1
[1 1] 2
[1 2] 3
[1 3] 4
[2 0] 2
[2 1] 3
[2 2] 4
[3 0] 3
[3 1] 4
[4 0] 4
```